# how can I call a method as I click UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I want to ask that how can I call a method as I do click(touch for start writing) in iphone UITextField, as like we click UIButton and put method in "addTarget", is there any way for UITextFields ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

implement a [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) and do whatever you want to do in `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` or `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

You should use the first method if you want to stop the textfield from behaving like a textfield. For example if you want to open the textfield editor in a modal view. You can return NO there if you don't want this behavior.

---

Edit: Here is the code to call myMethod:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    [self myMethod]; 
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: I want to just call a method that is defined by me, as I tap the textfield, can u tell me code of it, my method signature is -(void) myMethod;

Comment: Remember to check if you have a UITextField or a UITextView. They behave very similarly but require separate delegates and functions (textViewShouldBeginEditing, UITextViewDelegate etc) - I didn't think to check and spent some time not understanding why my functions weren't being called

Comment: This will work only for the first click. If the user clicked again the delegate method textFieldDidBeginEditing will not be called

Comment: @user1366265 - that depends. If `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` ends with `return NO;`, then it won't go into the text editing mode, and every click on it will call `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` again. If it ends with `return YES;`, then it will be in text editing mode, and something must occur to END that editing mode, before it can begin again. For example, clicking on some other control.

Answer (score 3):

You can set textField's delegate and implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method in it - that method will get called when user taps the field and before it goes into editing.

See `UITextFieldDelegate` reference for more methods available.

Comment: how can I do as U said, I have already implemented this method, but I want to call a method that is user defined, so can U can me code, my method signature is -(void) myMethod;

Comment: Why you don't want to use delegate method? You can also listen to UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification notification with your custom method as notification handler, but that will fire when editing already began...

Answer (score 2):

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void) myMethod:(id)sender
{
    UITextField* textField =  (UITextField *)sender;

}
```

i think this will help..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can code as,

```
[YourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];

-(void)myMethod
{
 [YourTextField resignFirstResponder];
 //Do whatever you want
}
```